# Cassandra: POCO List Column of UDT in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, cassandra

I need a help from you ...

I'm developing a solution using the Cassandra Data Base and DataStax driver for C# to generate POCO code to generate the column family to the database, the problem is that I'm mapping wanting to map a column that is a UDT dictionary and is not operating, below the code so that someone can help me ...

Maps.cs

```
For<Users>()
            .TableName("Users")
            .PartitionKey(key => key.UsersId)
            .Column(u => u.UsersId, map => map.WithName("UsersId"))
            .Column(u => u.ImgProfileUrl, map => map.WithName("ImgProfileUrl"))
            .Column(u => u.Name, map => map.WithName("Name"))
            .Column(u => u.Gender, map => map.WithName("Gender"))
            .Column(u => u.UserName, map => map.WithName("UserName"))
            .Column(u => u.UserPassword, map => map.WithName("UserPassword"))
            .Column(u => u.DateOfBorn, map => map.WithName("DateOfBorn"))
            .Column(u => u.OpeningDate, map => map.WithName("OpeningDate"))
            .Column(u => u.FederalRegistrationCode, map => map.WithName("FederalRegistrationCode"))
            .Column(u => u.StateRegistrationCode, map => map.WithName("StateRegistrationCode"))
            .Column(u => u.TownRegistrationCode, map => map.WithName("TownRegistrationCode"))
            .Column(u => u.Score, map => map.WithName("Score"))
            .Column(u => u.Type, map => map.WithName("Type"))
            .Column(u => u.Status, map => map.WithName("Status"))
            .Column(u => u.DateOfCreated, map => map.WithName("DateOfCreated"))
            .Column(u => u.Tags, map => map.WithName("Tags"))
            .Column(u => u.Contacts, map => map.AsFrozen());
```

Entities Column Family

```
public class Users
{
    public Guid UsersId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ImgProfileUrl { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string UserPassword { get; set; }
    public int? Gender { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateOfBorn { get; set; }
    public DateTime? OpeningDate { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public string FederalRegistrationCode { get; set; }
    public string StateRegistrationCode { get; set; }
    public string TownRegistrationCode { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfCreated { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Tags { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<contactsudt> Contacts { get; set; }
}
```

Entities UDT

```
public class contactsudt
{
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Celular { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public long Number { get; set; }
    public string District { get; set; }
    public string Postalcode { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

Configuration Instance

```
new Configuration<contactsudt, Users>();
new Table<Users>(UtilsDb.Session).CreateIfNotExists();
```

Comment: What does "is not operating," mean? Failing to compile, goes wrong at run time with an error?

Comment: I have the following error returned Unknown Cassandra target type for CLR type AccessDataCql.Migrations.Entities.contactsudt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you're [registering your UDT](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/csharp-driver/3.0/csharp-driver/reference/21features/mappingUdts.html) with the session object whenever you bootstrap/create the session before you try to use it. For example, to use auto-mapping:

```
session.UserDefinedTypes.Define(
  UdtMap.For<contactsudt>()
        .Automap()
);
```

Also, make sure to [register your maps](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/csharp-driver/3.0/csharp-driver/reference/linqComponent.html?scroll=linq-component__linq-comp-configuration) (in Maps.cs in the example you gave) with the global MappingConfiguration so that LINQ will know about it:

```
MappingConfiguration.Global.Define<Maps>();
```

It sounds like you're probably missing the user defined type map.

Comment: Thank you, their response saved my life,because i was  thee hours trying to solve this....